# Adding cells to the menu in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a menu that opens from the left side of the screen when the menu opens, a dynamic generated menu cells appear on the screen. Can I add two static cells to it such as login and settings, all the way at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement table view data source, you can return number of dynamic cells + number of predefined cells.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in this case should handle this and depending on `NSIndexPath` return an appropriate cell.

Assuming that last two cells of table view should be login and settings it's pretty straightforward how to implement a data source, for example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return NumberOfDynamicCells + 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == NumberOfDynamicCells) {
        LoginCellView* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoginCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.titleLabel.text = @"Log in";

        return cell;
    } else if(indexPath.row == NumberOfDynamicCells + 1) {
        SettingsCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SettingsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.titleLabel.text = @"Settings";

        return cell;
    } else {
        DynamicCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DynamicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do this with two different tableviews? One for the dynamic and one for static. The reason I want to do this is I want to login and settings to all the way at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You can but this is weird. Maybe you should consider to avoid tableview then at all and put two static buttons at the bottom of your sidebar?

Comment: I cannot I have to use second table.